# How to get depth in mysql store procedure recursion?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, recursion

I have a recursive **mysql stored procedures** for which I have set the **`max_sp_recursion_depth=10.`**

Now, *without setting a local variable*, i would like to know what recursion's level is during single execution.

I think that surely there is a session variable that stores the depth (how else would you know when you reach the maximum level) but I could not find it. I would avoid using a variable to do this incrementally. How could i know this (if any) system variable?

Comment: Why are you using recursion?  Perhaps you can avoid it with a different data structure.

Comment: Let me rephrase:  Why are you using recursion?  SQL is not intended to be used in this fashion.  You can almost certainly avoid it with a different data structure.

Answer (score 2):

I know you specifically asked how to do this *without* a user-created variable - but for others coming across this thought it would be worth posting how to do it *with* one as it's fairly simple:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_recursive
BEGIN
  // ... DECLAREs here

  -- Set maximum recursion depth (max is 255)
  SET @@SESSION.max_sp_recursion_depth = 10;

  -- Increment current recursion depth
  SET @recursion_depth = IFNULL(@recursion_depth + 1, 1);
  
  -- ... More stored procedure code

  -- Decrement current recursion depth. Note: Care must be taken to ensure this line
  -- is *always* executed at the end of the stored procedure.
  SET @recursion_depth = @recursion_depth - 1;
END
```

**Explanation**

The `@recursion_depth` session-scoped variable is incremented by the above `SET` statement each time the stored procedure is entered. The first time it is entered, the variable is uninitialized and so has a value of `NULL` - this is checked for by the `IFNULL()`, which reassigns it to one in this case. At the end of the stored procedure just before exiting, the depth needs to be decremented.

**Further notes**

Worth noting that SQL Server *does* provide an in-built `@@NESTLEVEL` variable for doing the above - but unfortunately MySQL doesn't seem to have an equivalent.