# mysql internal join of all sons of a parent

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I have a table structured as

```
Id int(10)
Parent int(10) --reference I'd
Name
```

This table contain organization structure. Example data

```
Id | parent | name
 1     Null       organization A
 2     1            Office A
 3     1            Office B
 4     3            Room 1
 5     3            Room 2
```

`

This example simple map that org. A have 2 offices,
Office B have 2 rooms .

Parent field hold either null (if no parent -end node-) or an Id of parent.

I want to fetch all rows of a parent row

I want my query to return all child's and children of children.

Can I do this with one query ?

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: T-SQL supports common table expressions (CTE's) that can recursively join itself until it reaches the youngest children, but unfortunately this isn't possible in mysql with just a simple query.  It is possible to get the data you want, but not easy.  Here is another article you can read up on: [http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a fixed hierarchy depth, I can't think of how you could do it with one query in MySQL (could always be mistaken). If you have hierarchy depth of less than 255 you can do it with a single call to previously created recursive procedures like below.

Inner Procedure Inner

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `parent_child`(in `I_Parent` int)
BEGIN
  DECLARE `V_done` INT;
  DECLARE `V_Id` INT;
  DECLARE `V_Parent` INT;
  DECLARE `V_Name` VARCHAR(45);
  DECLARE `cur1` CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM  `stackoverflow`.`parent_child` WHERE `Parent` = `I_Parent`;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET `V_done` = TRUE; 

  INSERT INTO `stackoverflow`.`parent_child_temp` SELECT `Id`, `Parent`, `Name` FROM `stackoverflow`.`parent_child` WHERE `Parent` IS NULL AND `Id` = `I_Parent`;

  OPEN `cur1`;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH `cur1` INTO `V_Id`, `V_Parent`, `V_Name` ;
    IF `V_done` THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    INSERT  INTO `stackoverflow`.`parent_child_temp` SELECT `V_Id`, `V_Parent`, `V_Name`;
    CALL `stackoverflow`.`parent_child`(V_Id);

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE `cur1`;
END
```

Wrapper Procedure Inner

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `parent_child_wrapper`(in `I_WrapperParent` int)
BEGIN
    SET @@SESSION.max_sp_recursion_depth = 255;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `stackoverflow`.`parent_child_temp`;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `stackoverflow`.`parent_child_temp` (id int, parent int, name varchar(45));
    CALL `stackoverflow`.`parent_child`(`I_WrapperParent`);
    SELECT * FROM `stackoverflow`.`parent_child_temp`;
END
```

Call SQL
    CALL `stackoverflow`.`parent_child_wrapper`(1);

**References**
*http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html
*[How I query (with mysql) column names that "unfortunately" have round brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771976/how-i-query-with-mysql-column-names-that-unfortunately-have-round-brackets)
*http://www.sitepoint.com/cursors-mysql-stored-procedures/
*[How to echo print statements while executing a sql script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147834/how-to-echo-print-statements-while-executing-a-sql-script)
*http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_sp_recursion_depth
*[MySql :: stored procedure recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315343/mysql-stored-procedure-recursive)
*http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-temporary-tables.htm
*[How to get depth in mysql store procedure recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351065/how-to-get-depth-in-mysql-store-procedure-recursion)